# Regarding the difference between Metropolis-Hastings and Wolff algorithm (synchronous vs asynchronous) applied to Ising Model?

Tags: python, algorithms, computational-physics, monte-carlo

I am trying to self-learn concepts at the intersection of physics and programming. When reading up on the Ising Model, I find that the typical programming tutorial (such as [this one](https://sites.physics.wustl.edu/gradcomputer/wiki/images/6/63/Ising_notes_v2.pdf)) covers the Metropollis-Hastings algorithm; most online resources show this algorithm being used to flip one spin-state at a time until the stopping criteria is reached. I was thinking that it might make more physical sense to flip multiple states at one time instead of sequentially flipping one at a time (like synchronous vs asynchronous updates). While reading articles on wikipedia, I came across the [Wolff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolff_algorithm), which does perform multiple updates at once. The wikipedia article is very vague about how the Wolff algorithm works. I would like to better understand the reasons for the synchronous vs asynchronous version of Metropolis-Hastings, and would like to fully understand how the Wolff algorithm works.

1. Aside from the single-vs-multiple updates per iteration, are there more differences between the Metropolis-Hastings and Wolff algorithms?
2. Why do the Metropolis-Hastings tutorials typically show one sequential flip to another (instead of multiple flips at once)?
3. Can you recommend a good source to better understand the Wolff algorithm? I would like to code both methods and compare output.